# Combine arrays to one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, reduce

lets say i have the following array, how can i achieve the last given example in my this question by modifing the given reduce function?

i have tried to assign [cur] to a plans key but it only puts the first element out.

i have the feeling it have something to do with the way i concat the objects but i cant figure it out on my own.

```
{
   employee: 'employee_1',
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1',
   },
   startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
}, {
   employee: 'employee_2',
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1',
   },
   startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
}, {
   employee: 'employee_3',
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1',
   },
   startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
}
```

```
plans.reduce(function(o, cur) {

   // Get the index of the key-value pair.
   var occurs = o.reduce(function(n, item, i) {
      return (item.customer.toString() === cur.customer.toString()) ? i : n;
   }, -1);

   // If the name is found,
   if (occurs >= 0) {
      // append the current value to its list of values.
      o[occurs].employee = o[occurs].employee.concat(cur.employee)
      o[occurs].startdate = o[occurs].startdate.concat(cur.startdate)

   // Otherwise
   } else {

      // add the current item to o (but make sure the value is an array).
      var obj = {
         customer: cur.customer,
         employee: [cur.employee],
         startdate: [cur.startdate]
      };
      o = o.concat([obj]);
   }
   return o;
}, [])
```

this reduces the given array to something like this:

```
{
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1'
   },
   employee: [{
     employee: 'employee_1'
   }, {
     employee: 'employee_2'
   }, {
     employee: 'employee_3'
   }],
   startdate: [{
     startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
   }, {
     startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
   }, {
     startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
   }]  
}
```

But what i need is something like this:

```
{
   customer: {customer_data},
   plans: [{
     employee: 'employee_1',
     startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z' 
   }, {
     employee: 'employee_2',
     startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z' 
   }, {
     employee: 'employee_3',
     startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z' 
   }]
}
```

Comment: _how can i achieve the last given result_ Looking at the desired output, it doesn't really look like you want to achieve the last given result, but rather a group by `customer`, isn't it?

Comment: yes thats what i try to achieve ps: edited the question for better understanding

Comment: The input, imho, is still quite unclear. I will still try to help, perhaps this can give you some ideas: https://jsfiddle.net/a3n6fcwd/1/

Comment: Thank you, it works, however there is another answer that helped me alot! Thanks to you booth!

Comment: Accept the answer below, hope you learnt something out of both ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your solution so as to get the desired output .

Instead of using reduce , you should use find method to check if customer already exists in the array .
Also you were not taking into consideration the plans array , I have added that.

```js
var plans = [
{
   employee: 'employee_1',
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1',
   },
   startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
}, {
   employee: 'employee_2',
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1',
   },
   startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
}, {
   employee: 'employee_3',
   customer: {
     name: 'customer_1',
   },
   startdate: '2020-03-01T23:00:00.000Z'
}
];


var result = plans.reduce(function(o, cur) {

   // Get the index of the key-value pair.
   var occurs = o.find(ob=> ob.customer.name === cur.customer.name);

   // If the name is found,
   if (occurs) {
      // append the current value to its list of values.
      occurs.plans.push( {employee: cur.employee,
          startdate: cur.startdate}  )
   // Otherwise
   } else {

      // add the current item to o (but make sure the value is an array).
      var obj = {
         customer: cur.customer,
         plans:[
          {employee: cur.employee,
          startdate: cur.startdate}
         ]
      };
      o = o.concat(obj);
   }
   return o;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```